Shared memory data send from C# to c++ memory leak
I am sending point cloud data from C# through to c++ in Unreal Engine. The data is doubles, and varies in size per send. I have the below code running perfectly, but I am seeing a small, but definite memory leak. When I start the c++ side, my memory use rises, and keeps rising.
I have tried setting the memory after read with :
std::memset(SharedMemoryData, 0, (numPoints*3)*sizeof(double));

as well as calculating the used memory with:
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION
        memorySize = static_cast<size_t>(memInfo.RegionSize);

and resetting that.
I have checked all variables are being reset and released. What am I missing here?
C# (sender)
MemoryMappedFile mmf = null;
        Mutex mutex = null;


    public void ProcessingEventHandler(object sender, DLLFunctions.ProcessingEventArgsPoints args)
            {
                if (mmf == null)
                {
                    long maxSize = 1100000; //  doubles * 8 bytes per double
                    mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("SharedMemoryTest", maxSize);
    
                    mutex = new Mutex(true, "SharedMemoryTestMutex", out mutexCreated);
    
                }
    
                if (mmf != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                        {
                            // Acquire the mutex
                            mutex.WaitOne();
    
                            try
                            {
                                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(stream))
                                {
                                    // Write the count of valid doubles first
                                    bw.Write(Convert.ToDouble(args.num));
    
                                    foreach (double value in args.pointData)
                                    {
                                        bw.Write(value);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                // Ensure the mutex is always released
                                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                             
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // Handle exceptions appropriately
                        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }


c++ inside Unreal Engine(reciever)
The OpenMappedMemory function is called once, then the GetMappedMemoryData function is called every Tick.
//header
    static bool OpenMappedMemory(const FString& sharedMemoryName);
        static TArray<FLidarPointCloudPoint> GetMappedMemoryData();
        static void CloseSharedMemory();
        //to lidar points
        static TArray<FLidarPointCloudPoint> Points;
    
        static void* SharedMemoryHandle; // Mapped memory handle.
        static double* SharedMemoryData; // Pointer to memory data.

//.cpp
#include "SharedMemory.h"
    
#include <windows.h>

constexpr size_t MAX_EXPECTED_SIZE = 1100000;
size_t memorySize = 0;
void* SharedMemory::SharedMemoryHandle; // Mapped memory handle.
double* SharedMemory::SharedMemoryData; // Pointer to memory data.
TArray<FLidarPointCloudPoint> SharedMemory::Points;
HANDLE MutexHandle = nullptr;
SharedMemory::SharedMemory()
{
}

SharedMemory::~SharedMemory()
{
    CloseSharedMemory();
}
bool SharedMemory::OpenMappedMemory(const FString& sharedMemoryName)
{

    MutexHandle = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, false, TEXT("SharedMemoryTestMutex"));
    if (MutexHandle == nullptr) {
        UE_LOG(LogClass, Log, TEXT("Could not open mutex."));
        return false;
    }


    SharedMemoryHandle = OpenFileMapping(
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // File Mapping Security and Access Rights
        true,         // Do not inherit the handle
        *sharedMemoryName);

    if (!SharedMemoryHandle)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogClass, Log, TEXT("Memory-mapped file does not exist."));
        return false;
    }

    
    // Map view of the file
    SharedMemoryData = static_cast<double*>(MapViewOfFile(SharedMemoryHandle,
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
        0, 0,
        MAX_EXPECTED_SIZE)); // 0 to map the entire file


    // Calculate the memory size
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION memInfo;
    if (VirtualQuery(SharedMemoryData, &memInfo, sizeof(memInfo)) == 0)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogClass, Log, TEXT("Failed to query memory information."));
        UnmapViewOfFile(SharedMemoryData);
        SharedMemoryData = nullptr;
        CloseHandle(SharedMemoryHandle);
        CloseHandle(MutexHandle);
        SharedMemoryHandle = nullptr;
        MutexHandle = nullptr;
        return false;
    }

    // The size of the memory region is stored in the RegionSize member of MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION
    memorySize = static_cast<size_t>(memInfo.RegionSize);

     
  //  UE_LOG(LogClass, Log, TEXT("memory information. %d"), memorySize);

    return true;
}

TArray<FLidarPointCloudPoint> SharedMemory::GetMappedMemoryData()
{
    Points.Empty();    

    if (!SharedMemoryData) {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Memory-mapped data does not exist."));
        return Points;
    }


    size_t numPoints = static_cast<size_t>(SharedMemoryData[0]);
    try {
       
        // Read data from shared memory
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numPoints; i += 3) {
            size_t baseIndex = 1 + i;
            double x = SharedMemoryData[baseIndex] * 100;
            double y = SharedMemoryData[baseIndex + 1] * 100;
            double z = SharedMemoryData[baseIndex + 2] * 100;

            auto Point = MakeUnique<FLidarPointCloudPoint>(FVector3f(x, y, z));
            Point->Color = FColor::Red;
            Points.Add(MoveTemp(*Point));
        }
    }
    catch (...) {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Exception occurred while reading shared memory data."));
    }
  //  std::memset(SharedMemoryData, 0, (numPoints*3)*sizeof(double));



    return Points;
}


void SharedMemory::CloseSharedMemory()
{
    if (SharedMemoryData != nullptr)
    {
        UnmapViewOfFile(SharedMemoryData);
        SharedMemoryData = nullptr;
    }

    if (SharedMemoryHandle != nullptr)
    {
        CloseHandle(SharedMemoryHandle);
        SharedMemoryHandle = nullptr;
    }
    if (MutexHandle != nullptr)
    {
        CloseHandle(MutexHandle);
        MutexHandle = nullptr;
    }
}



memset should not matter. I presume either C# or C++ leaking the shared memory.

This snippet of code looks suspicious:
auto Point = MakeUnique<FLidarPointCloudPoint>(FVector3f(x, y, z));
Points.Add(MoveTemp(*Point));

MakeUnique allocates a TUniquePtr that is immediately copied from and discarded. If the memory allocator is not good at reusing memory this can result in fragmentation.
Instead (without knowing the definition of FLidarPointCloudPoint), why not do:
Points.Emplace(FVector3f(x,y,z));


nice catch. Perhaps worth mentioning that otherwise there is no (obvious) leak in the code.

I was a bit at a loss on how to phrase it beyond "fragmentation"

Thanks you! I have made that change,  but I still see the leak.
Digging in more, the memory rise once I start to read the data. So in the tick, where GetMappedMemoryDatais used.

Yes, memory mappings count towards your application's memory usage, but not the working set (sometimes called resident set size), which is what you should be measuring as "memory usage".

and should I be 'freeing' that memory somehow in my loop?

File-backed memory can always be flushed when in need of memory and reloaded when it is read again. You should count this towards your memory usage, but maybe your memory leak is elsewhere in the program. Have you used a memory profiler to see where the new allocations come from?
